# Redirecting input value to search a page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry, I am just learning so I apologize for my confusing code..

How would i take an input value and redirect it as a search within another help system such as madcap?

I created a bootstrap page that has a search in the hero banner and in this search id like it to redirect to our help system and search there. Here is an example of what I am trying to create:

https://webfiles.blackbaud.com/files/support/helpfiles/education/k12/full-help/Content/Home.html

When you use the search on this home page you'll see that it redirects to their help system search. I hope this makes sense? Being new to this makes it hard for me to explain..

I'm not sure if my HTML or javascript is correct. This is what I have at the moment:

```
<div class="form">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            <input type="text" onkeypress="return search(this)" class="form-control form-input" placeholder="Search anything..." aria-label="Large" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
          </div>
```

This is my JS:

```
  function search(this) {
if(addEventListener.key === 'Enter') {
  window.location = "https://help.madcapsoftware.com/flare2021r2/Default.htm#cshid=&searchQuery="
  return false;     
}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This question is unclear. It missing details and clarity. What is supposed to happen? what is the desired result? A possible solution depends on the search engine/page, how they work etc.

Comment: `addEventListener` makes no sense. You should be using an event

Comment: Sorry, I am just learning so i apologize for my confusing code. I created a bootstrap page that has a search and in this search id like it to redirect to our help system and search there. Here is an example of what I am trying to create: https://webfiles.blackbaud.com/files/support/helpfiles/education/k12/full-help/Content/Home.html when you use the search on this home page you'll see that it redirects to their help system search. Does that make sense? Being new to this makes it hard for me to explain...

Answer (score 0):

My answer removes the inline javascript and adds a keydown event listener and checks for the enter key, then redirects if the enter key was pressed.

```js
let search = document.querySelector(".form .form-input");

search.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    window.location = "https://help.madcapsoftware.com/flare2021r2/Default.htm#cshid=&searchQuery=" + this.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" placeholder="Search anything..." aria-label="Large" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am just learning so i apologize for my confusing code. I created a bootstrap page that has a search and in this search id like it to redirect to our help system and search there. Here is an example of what I am trying to create: https://webfiles.blackbaud.com/files/support/helpfiles/education/k12/full-help/Content/Home.html when you use the search on this home page you'll see that it redirects to their help system search. I hope this makes sense. Thank you so much for your feedback, I'll give that a try!